# Again, improper integrals involving $\ln(1+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

How can I check for which values of $\alpha $ this integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^\alpha}\,dx $$ converges?

I managed to do this in $0$ because I know $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ near 0.

I have no idea how to do this in $\infty$ where nothing is known about $\ln(x)$ .

Will someone help me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large values of $x$, we can build the expansion
$$  
\log[1 + x^2] = 2 \log[x] + \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2 x^4} + \frac{1}{3 x^6} - \frac{1}{4 x^8}   
$$
So, I think that the only problem is now to compute the antiderivative of $\log[x] / x^a$ which is quite simple using integration by parts ($u = \log[x]$ , $v'= 1 / x^a$).

The result is $\frac{x^{1-a} \log[x]}{1-a} - \frac{x^{1-a}}{1-a)^2}$

Remember how behave the product of $x$ to power by $\log[x]$. You then arrive to what Olivier was telling.

I hope that this clarifies. If not, just post and we shall continue. Cheers.

Comment: How is this the taylor expansion of our function? How did $2log(x)$ arrived to our Taylor expansion ? Thanks !

Comment: Log[1+x^2] = Log[x^2] + Log[(1+x^2)/x^2] = Log[x^2] + Log[1+1/x^2] = 2 Log[x] + Log[1+1/x^2]

Comment: I think I got it. I will reread it in a few hours to verify everything, but I think I got it. THanks  a lot!

Comment: @homogenity.You welcome. It has been my pleasure to work with you.

Comment: @homogenity. What Felix Marin wrote is beautiful...issimo ! Please forgive the picoscopic quality of my answer. Cheers.

Comment: This looks very similar to what you'd get when normally integrating $$\int log\left|x\right|\:dx,$$ so it must be a close-knit family of integrals, i.e. anything that looks like what he's described, and as long as what we're logging is a polynomial it should take this basic form. Perhaps it can be applied further to log's of trigonometric, exponential (of course, and given that hyperbolic-trigonometric) and other logs. Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> The integral converges whenever $\ds{1 < \Re\alpha < 3}$ as it has been proved above by $\tt\mbox{@Olivier Bégassat}$.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
=
\overbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - 1}^{\alpha/2}}\,\half\,
\pars{x - 1}^{-1/2}\,\dd x}^{\ds{1 + x^{2} \to x}}
=
\half\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - 1}^{\pars{\alpha + 1}/2}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\half\overbrace{\int_{1}^{0}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over \pars{1/x - 1}^{\pars{\alpha + 1}/2}}\,
\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}}^{\ds{x \to {1 \over x}}}
=
-\,\half\int^{1}_{0}
{x^{\pars{\alpha - 3}/2}\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{1 - x}^{\pars{\alpha + 1}/2}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
-\,\half\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int^{1}_{0}
{x^{\mu + \pars{\alpha - 3}/2}\pars{1 - x}^{-\pars{\alpha + 1}/2}}\,\dd x
=
-\,\half\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{{\rm B}\pars{\mu + \alpha/2 - 1/2,1/2 - \alpha/2}}{\mu}
\end{align}
where ${\rm B}\pars{x,y}$ is the $\it Beta$ function:
$$
{\rm B}\pars{a,b} \equiv \int_{0}^{1}t^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{b - 1}\,\dd t\,,\qquad
\Re a >0\,,\quad \Re b > 0
$$

> With the identity
> $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{a,b} ={\Gamma\pars{a}\Gamma\pars{b} \over \Gamma\pars{a + b}}}$
> $\ds{\pars{~\Gamma\pars{z}\ \mbox{is the}\ {\it Gamma}\ \mbox{function}~}}$: 
> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x=
> -\,\half\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
> {\Gamma\pars{\mu + \alpha/2 - 1/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2 - \alpha/2}
>   \over \Gamma\pars{\mu}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,\Gamma\pars{\half - {\alpha \over 2}}\lim_{\mu \to 0}
> \partiald{}{\mu}
> \bracks{\mu\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2 + \mu} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + \mu}}
> \end{align}
> where we used the identity $\Gamma\pars{z + 1} = z\Gamma\pars{z}$.

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
=
-\,\half\,\Gamma\pars{\half - {\alpha \over 2}}\times\lim_{\mu \to 0}\!\!\!
\braces{\!\!\!%
\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2 + \mu}
+ \mu\Psi\pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2 + \mu}}\Gamma\pars{1 + \mu}
- \Psi\pars{1 + \mu}\bracks{\mu\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2 + \mu}}
\over \Gamma\pars{1 + \mu}\!\!\!}
\end{align}
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \equiv \totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}}{z}}$ is the $\it digamma$
function.

> With $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1} = 1}$ and the identity
> $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}\Gamma\pars{1 - z} = {\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}}}$:
> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x\\[3mm]&=
> -\,\half\,\Gamma\pars{\half - {\alpha \over 2}}\Gamma\pars{{\alpha \over 2} - \half}
> =-\,\half\,
> {\pi \over \Gamma\pars{1/2 + \alpha/2}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{1/2 - \alpha/2}}}
> \Gamma\pars{{\alpha \over 2} - \half}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,{\pi \over \cos\pars{\pi\alpha/2}}
> {\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2 + \alpha/2}}
> =-\half\,\pi\sec\pars{\pi\alpha \over 2}\,
> {\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2} \over \pars{\alpha/2 - 1/2}\Gamma\pars{-1/2 + \alpha/2}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x^{\alpha}}\,\dd x
=
-\,{\pi\sec\pars{\pi\alpha/2} \over \alpha - 1}\,,\qquad
1 < \Re\alpha < 3}
$$

Comment: This is just splendid ! Thank you very much for such an answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You're welcome.

Comment: How can I evaluate the integral (between $1< \alpha < 3$) using complex analysis theorems etc.?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5):

To check integrability at the vicinity of $0$, use
$$\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^{\alpha}}\sim\frac{1}{x^{\alpha-2}}$$
which is integrable *iff* $\alpha-2<1$.
At $+\infty$, one has
$$\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x^{\alpha}}\sim\frac{2\ln(x)}{x^{\alpha}}.$$
It is not very difficult to prove that

> For all $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$,
>   $$\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}\ln(x)^{\beta}}$$
>   is integrable at the vicinity of $+\infty$ *iff* either $\alpha>1$ or $\alpha=1$ and $\beta>1$

It follows that your function is integrable on $\Bbb R^*_+$ *iff* $1<\alpha<3$.

Comment: Begassat: As I wrote in the question itself, I know how to do it in $0$, and my main problem is at $\infty$ , where I have no idea what to do... SO, will you help me understand how to solve my question, without the claim you quoted? Which function should I put in order to estimate the corresponding limit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I suggest you develop $\log(1+x^2)$ as an infinite series (Taylor); divide each term by $x^a$, compute the anti-derivative and look where and when arrive the problems when you compute the integral between zero and infinity.

Comment: Tried it, but I get $\frac{x^2}{x^\alpha} - \frac{x^4}{2x^\alpha}+... $ . The first term has an integral in an infinite region if $\alpha-2 >1 $ , i.e. $ \alpha>3 $ , and this does not correspond to the result Olivier gave me...

Comment: In fact, we actually need to take $\alpha \to \infty$ in order for the integral on each term to converge... This is because each term is of the order of $x^{2n} $ , and for the antiderivative to converge at $\infty$ , we need $2n-\alpha +1 $<-1$  for every $n$ .

Comment: What am I  getting wrong here?

Comment: @homogenity. I apologize since my approach seems to be totally wrong. I made a detailed numerical study of this integral which I found to have finite values for the range : a strictly larger than 1 and a smaller or equal to 3. This is exactly what Olivier gave. Again, sorry to have given a wrong track ! Cheers.

Comment: thanks a lot. But how can I show this formally ? (i.e.- how can I prove that this integral converges only when $1<\alpha < 3 $ ? I have no idea how to do it, and it seems like Olivier doesn't answer this post anymore

Comment: @homogenity. I think that the approach used by Olivier is a quite nice formal proof.

Comment: But I have no idea how to prove its approach. He quoted a theorem without giving me any proof of it , and I have no idea how to handle it.. My problem is (as I said) with infinity , and I don't know how to deal with $ln(1+x^2)$ over there. Will you please help me?

Comment: @homogenity. I write another answer for having more room than in a comment.